# Unable to Post a csv file in Postman, getting 400 error

Tags: postman

I am trying to post a csv file and get the fields(fields in the csv file)  in the response using Postman but I am getting 400 Bad request error.
Error:
{
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Required request part 'inFile' is not present",
  "timeStamp": "Tue Feb 07 00:00:17 EST 2017",
  "trace": "org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'inFile' is not present\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.java:192)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite....}
Please let me know how to overcome this issue as I am new to this.

[image: Form_Data_error]

Comment: you didn't specify a key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to give a name to your `form-data` parameter.

According to the error you got the name of the key should be "inFile".

And you need to input it here:
[image]